# Variable and executable in a shell interpreter

Tags: c, shell, interpreter

Do you know, how make the difference between variable and executable in a shell interpretor? Because i don't know how i can do that in my lexer.
If anyone have an idea ^^

Thanks,
Have a nice day

Mathieu

Comment: Have you tried examining the context in which it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal Posix-style shell, the first "word" in a statement which is not a variable assignment is the command to execute. Variable assignments have the form `name=value` where there cannot be any whitespace around the <kbd>=</kbd> and the `name` is a valid variable name.

Other than that, and in arithmetic evaluation context (which is not required for basic shells), any use of a variable must be preceded by a <kbd>$</kbd>.

Identifying assignments is contextual, but it is easy to do since the <kbd>=</kbd> is mandatory. In a flex-style lexer you could enable and disable assignment recognition with appropriate start conditions, for example.

Without knowing anything more about your strategy for lexical analysis, it's hard to provide a more detailed answer.

If you care about compatibility with Posix shell syntax, the description can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html).

Comment: That's exactly what i was thinking but i wasn't sure (i don't know a lot about shell).
So thanks ^^